# find the last match with java/regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a dynamic text that contains "font-family", for example:

```
    style="font-family: &quot;Calibri&quot;,&quot;sans-serif&quot;; font-size:11pt";
```

And I want to remove all the font-family element.

I was using this code

```
    patron = Pattern.compile("font-family:(.*?);");
    encaja = patron.matcher(cadena);
     nueva = encaja.replaceAll("");
```

But it remove in a way that isn't useful for me:

```
    style="Calibri&quot;,&quot;sans-serif&quot;; font-size: 11pt;"
```

What I want is:

```
    style=" font-size: 11pt;"
```

I also tried  using this pattern

```
    font-family:[^(&.*;)]*?;
```

But it doesn't work.

Can you help me?

Thanks

EDIT

More case examples:

```
in: style="font-size:15px; font-family:Arial; mso-ascii-theme-font: minor-latin; "
output: style="font-size:15px;  mso-ascii-theme-font: minor-latin;"

in: style="font-family:Arial,A&aacute;s;; font-size:11pt; mso-fareast-mso-fareast-theme-font: minor-latin;"
output:style="font-size:11pt; mso-fareast-mso-fareast-theme-font: minor-latin;"
```

Comment: Please give more edge case examples of input and desired output. I sure there is a one line solution, but I'm not sure what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
String result = yourstr.replaceAll("(?i)font-family:(?>[^;&\"]++|&(?>quot|ntilde);)*(?>;\\s*+|(?=\"))", "");
```

pattern description:

```
(?i)           # make the pattern case-insensitive
font-family:
(?>            # open an atomic group
    [^;&\"]++  # all characters except ; & and " one or more times (possessive)
  |            # OR
    &          # literal &
    (?>        # put the different possibilities here
        quot
      |
        ntilde
    )
    ;          # literal ;
)*             # repeat the atomic group zero or more times
(?>
    ;\\s*+     # literal ; and trailing spaces
  |
    (?=\")     # followed by " (last value of the attribute without trailing ; )
)
```

Another but less safer way (IMO): skip all letters that are between a `&` and a `;` :

```
String result = yourstr.replaceAll("(?i)font-family:(?>[^;&\"]++|&[a-z]++;)*(?>;\\s*+|(?=\"))", "");
```

Comment: I forgot to say that I can have another html code inside, for example &ntilde;

Comment: @OscarSan: You only need to add it in the alternation. see my edit.

Comment: +1 but why were the atomic groups needed? I always go for the shortest regex I can devise. Is there a significant benefit that outweighs the increased complexity/decreased readability?

Comment: @Bohemian: The first atomic group is essential if you want to avoid a catastrophic backtracking in the case (for example) there are not a `;` or a `"` in the string. The two others are not essential and can be replaced with a non-capturing group, but note that the pattern will not be smaller with non-capturing groups and that the regex engine don't have to record backtracking positions (in other words: the backtracking capability is not needed here).

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Thanks. I didn't notice the alternate optional CBT trap.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
newstr = str.replaceFirst("font-family:\s?([^\s]+)", "");
```

Comment: This will work provided that you will always keep one or more whitespace characters between each css property-value pair.